# Remove default line break after using an Ember-component in templates ofember-cli project

Tags: ember-components, grunt-ember-templates

when i use a ember-component for example

```
{{blog-post title=title}}
  {{/blog-post}}
<h1> Welcome to my Blog </h1>
```

I donot want a line break between component and htlml tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the component class's `tagName` [property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_tagName) to span. So:

```
{{blog-post title=title tagName="span"}}
  {{/blog-post}}
<h1> Welcome to my Blog </h1>
```